# How to make sure that my backbone view renders completely before any tests are executed using mocha and phantomjs?

Tags: backbone.js, phantomjs, mocha.js

Here is what i am doing

### My Test Script

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'application'], function($, app){
describe('View Products List', function(){
    // All test in this test suite fails    
    it('Products list should be present', function(done) {    
      $('.productlist').length.should.equal(1);  
      return done();
    });
    it('product list should be have a checkbox for product selection', function(done) {      
      $('.productlist td:first input[type=checkbox]').length.should.equal(1);  
      return done();
    });
    it('product name should be anchor which could be clickable', function(done) {
      $('.productlist td:first a').length.should.equal(1);  
      return done();enter code here
    });
    it('Should show product details on click of product name', function(done) {
      $('.productlist td:first a').click();
      $('.editproduct').length.should.equal(1);
      return done();
    });
 });
 });
```

### Backbone View

```
var Products = new Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : 'div'
template : productsTemplate
render: function() {
       $(this.el).html(this.template());
   }
 initialize: function() {
       // some code
   }
});
```

### Description

When i run my test script and load the url #products the products view is rendered to the html body. I want the test case to check for the DOM elements produced by the view. It seems like the tests runs first i.e before the view renders the dom elements hence it fails. how can we make sure that the view has rendered completely before my test run ?

Answer (score 0):

In Mocha async code should be included in a `beforeEach` section to be sure it is executed before the tests.

In your case try to re-render the view in this section :

```
beforeEach(function() {
    productListView.render();
});

describe('View Products List', function(){
    it("...
    ...
```

You can see this post for more details : http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/17/asynchronous-unit-tests-with-mocha-promises-and-winjs/